# How to remove field from a specific form

Tags: jquery, forms, selector

Using jquery, i would like to remove a hidden input, based on a class name selector but I just want to remove this inside of one specific form?

something like this:

```
$('.addToCartButton').click(function () {

    var form = $(this).closest('form');

    //remove all inputs with class name "test" inside of the form object above.

});
```

What is the best way of doing this?

### Update

---

As a follow up question, how can i
1. First read each input val() into a variable before i remove it?
2. Get the first element from the find method (as it could return multiple elements)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do it

```
$(form).find('input.test').remove();  //remove all elements
```

http://api.jquery.com/remove/

follow up:

```
var firstItem=$(form).find('input.test')[0]; // only the first item

var arr=[];  //this will build an array of the values
 $(form).find('input.test').each(function(){
    arr.push($(this).val());
  });

var arr=[];  //this will build an array of the names andvalues with a comma between
 $(form).find('input.test').each(function(){
    arr.push($(this).name + "," + $(this).val());
  });
```

loop through all values in array

```
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    alert(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: i added a follow up question as i just realized the answer to my first question doesn't fully solve my issue

Comment: What will this code `arr[]=$(this).val();` and `arr[]=$(this).name + "," + $(this).val();` do?

Comment: `arr[]=$(this).val();` <- that will add a new item to an array, the items text will be whatever is in that inputs `value="in here"`..... `arr[]=$(this).name + "," + $(this).val();` <- does the same thing, but it adds the name AND value to the array, with a comma seperating it.

Comment: @Johnny - Can you fiddle this `arr[]=$(this).val();` for me?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('.addToCartButton').click(function () {

    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    var inputValues = {};

    //remove all inputs with class name "test" inside of the form object above.
    form.find("input.test").remove();

    //This loop will put all the input name/value pair into inputValues object
    form.find("input.test").each(function(){
       inputValue[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
    });

    //This will give you the first input element
    form.find("input.test:first");

});
```

Comment: i added a follow up question as i just realized the answer to my first question doesn't fully solve my issue

Comment: i like this line: ` inputValue[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();`  better than the one i used, assuming he knows the names of each input.. would be simple to get the values later. it does the same as the lines i used that u asked about. but my line of code doesnt add a keyname, only a value.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var form = $(this).closest('form');
form.remove('.class_name');
```